# Difference between function return type value

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

I just wanted to know what is the difference in

`public Task somethod()` and `public int somethod()`

Comment: Are you sure this is correct syntax? Because in cannot be used as type.

Answer (score 5):

First method returns a `Task` type object.

Second method returns an [int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5kzh1b5w.aspx) type value.

Answer (score 2):

These functions return different types.

Answer (score 0):

There's a **big big** difference.

The [.Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321321.aspx) is commonly use for [async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156513.aspx)

and the `public int somethod()` in only returns [`int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5kzh1b5w.aspx)